# Calling Thrift python server from thrift javascript client (CORS) issue (FIXED using browser extension)

Tags: javascript, python, thrift

I am trying to connect to python thrift server from a javacript thrift client. Currently I am just using a tutorial code on which I will build later. The python server code can be found here  -> [Python server code](http://tkang.blogspot.ca/2010/07/thrift-server-client-in-python.html)

The javscript code is as follows

```
    thriftCall:function() {

    var transport = new Thrift.Transport("http://localhost:30303/pythonImpl/pythonServer");
    var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
    var client    = new HelloWorldClient(protocol);



    try {
        result = client.ping();
        cc.log(result);

        result = client.sayHello();
        cc.log(result);

        result = client.sayMsg(HELLO_IN_KOREAN);
        cc.log(result);
    }catch(ouch){
        cc.log("Problem!!!");
    }
}
```

When I try to connect I get the following error message on server

```
D:\Game Component Integration\Project\thriftPyTest\pythonImpl>pythonServer.py
Starting python server...
ERROR:thrift.server.TServer:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\thrift\server\TServer.py", line 88, in serve self.processor.process(iprot, oprot)
File "../gen-py\helloworld\HelloWorld.py", line 133, in process (name, type, seqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 140, in readMessageBegin 
name = self.trans.readAll(sz)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
chunk = self.read(sz - have)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 159, in read
self.__rbuf = StringIO(self.__trans.read(max(sz, self.__rbuf_size)))
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\thrift\transport\TSocket.py", line 105, in read
buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
MemoryError
```

I have no idea how to go about this issue . Same server works fine when called from python client. Any help or leads will really be appreciated.

Update : 
   I had to use a JSON protocol for python

```
handler = HelloWorldHandler()
processor = HelloWorld.Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=30303)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TJSONProtocol.TJSONProtocolFactory() #pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
port = 30303
#server = THttpServer.THttpServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
server = THttpServer.THttpServer(processor, ("localhost", port), pfactory)

print "Starting python server..."
server.serve()
print "done!"
```

So now js client CAN connect but I am getting this error

```
http://localhost:30303//pythonImpl/pythonServer. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I guess I have to add header while sending response from python server . Any Idea how ???

Thanks.

Udpate: Tried many things , didnt work . So just so that it would work , I simply added chrome extension that solves CORS issue. Extension can be found [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh) . Yet I would welcome any idea on fixing this issue in code itself.

Comment: Not sure about the cocos tag, but may I suggest to post that to the Thrift mailing list?

Comment: Yes I have posted there , will update here if at all they help me solve this issue and about cocos tag.. well its cause my project is on cocos-2d js .